# repetetively write to db or text file

Tags: java, database, crash

Short version:
if you had to save the current date and time every minute, overwriting the existing entry how would you do it?

writing it to a text file, a database, or a third option? And possibly, what would be considered best practice.

my scenario is i want to know, on application startup, when was the last time the application was running.

Long version:

I have a question of performance, and maybe also proper coding style.

i have an application that keeps track of a food stock, and when some things get stale and has to be removed.
There's a timertask running every minute checking the current items in stock and if they have exceeded the date and time where they are considered stale.

the issue is, if the application shuts down and restarts, items gone stale in during downtime will not have been checked.

code for the repeated method

```
runeveryminute = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

                for (Item i : lager.getAllItems) {

                    if (i.getMinutesTillStale == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(MainFrame.this,"WARNING",
                    "Alarm",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

I don't really agree to this way of checking if something has gone stale, but it's a school project so it isn't that important.

i added a window listener to the mainframe, but i'm uncertain if i can rely on it, to catch unexpected crashes, like power failure.

Comment: Why not just check on startup?

Comment: I think JavaFX could save you a lot of work and time. And Dave is right! Check on startup, or put a buton to do all the update!

Comment: Have you considered writing to file not every minute, but rather as part of the shutdown of your program?  So you write once when you turn off.

Comment: my idea was checking the time on startup, but on start up i would have to know when the application crashed.
Is there an "easy" way to do that i should know about?

Comment: @Thomas

i do that with the window listener, but as far as i know, i'm not able to catch the shutdown procedure during an unexpected crash

Comment: You could delete the file once you read it on load.  That way if the file is missing on load, it's either your first run or you had a crash.  You can then take Dave's suggestion and rescan through the entire stock with the new time.

Comment: This seams to be a lot of worry about a minor feature. Unless checking every item takes a really long time, checking on startup would not be a major performance drag. Besides, you can start your timer after checking, making it work one minute at a time. Another solution that might help you with performance issues is to collect all the getMinutesTillStale and store the smaller one, decreasing it whenever the timer starts. Hence, you would only need to do something when the counter came to zero.

Comment: i do check on startup, my question is about the shutting down part. if i don't know when the crash was i can't really tell what items went stale in the downtime.
I don't see how i would know approximately when the program crashed by daves suggestion.

Comment: On start, write a new entry to a file containing the current date and time. On normal completion write a second entry. You can now not only tell when you last checked (the second of two entries) but if you crashed (only one entry) or this is a fresh run (no file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how `i.getMinutesTillStale` is defined.
Will `getMinutesTillStale` give a negative value if an item has gone stale during downtime?
Then you can change the condition to `i.getMinutesTillStale <= 0`.

Suggestion:
Are you storing the items information in a database?
e.g., records like `itemId`, `datestored`, `expiryperiod(or dateofExpiry)`
Then you can write a stored procedure or a query with the timer time as the input.
It will check all the items which are expired and send you the list of those items.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: yes, if they have gone stale it will return a negative value. however what i want to avoid is creating alarms for items that have already caused an alarm.
if i only go by the minutestillstale method, i will alarm all the stale products, regardless of previous alarms.

Comment: @user744610 Is marking an item as "already alarmed" an option? What's to say you will always catch every single item that's expired RIGHT when it expires? I can't see the `== 0` being accurate if you are simply checking every minute. An item could have expired 30 seconds before the timer executed -- would `getMinutesTillStale == 0` for that item?

Comment: if there's no way to know exactly when the program crashed, that would be the next best thing, i suppose.